# How can I add reference to DataGridViewAutoFilter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm fairly inexperienced with windows system programming and now I'm continuing someones work but, before I can build the project I need to get rid of the warning:

```
The referenced component 'DataGridViewAutoFilter' could not be found.
```

I want to add a reference in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to DataGridViewAutoFilter

However its not in the .NET list when adding a reference. I know I can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23459) but, I'm not sure what to do with it because its just in a zip file and not a dll or installable onto my system. I fixed all the other dependencies by installing some stuff, but don't what to do in this case.

Anyone know how to install DataGridViewAutoFilter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the download link I provided is that of a c# project which will produce the DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll after building the sample code

Answer (score 6):

Steps to install ( add reference ):

1. Download zip file project [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23459)
2. Extract zip
3. Open the solution file **DataGridViewAutoFilter.sln** on CS or VB folder

Attention: This solution is Visual Studio 2005 version em .NET Framework 2.0

If you open on Visual Studio 2015 ( in case ), need open **Solution Explorer - Solution -> DataGridViewAutoFilter -> Properties ( double click )** and change Target framework **.NET Framework 2.0** to **4.5.1**, repeat this step to **DesignerSetupDemo** and **ProgrammaticSetupDemo**, Save All, Close Solution e Re-open solution.

4. Now, select **Debug** mode, project **DesignerSetupDemo** and click **Start** to run application. This app, run without errors, that's OK.
5. Open **Solution Explorer - Solution -> DesignerSetupDemo -> References** here is DataGridViewAutoFilter.

How check, on it install?

6. **Right click** on **References** and select **Add Reference...**. Look in **Projects -> Solution is marked (x) DataGridViewAutoFilter**

BINGO! You know DataGridViewAutoFilter project is feature reference.

**How build DataGridViewAutoFilter project to DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll file?**

7. **Right click** DataGridViewAutoFilter project and select **Build**

**Where is DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll file?**

8. DataGridViewAutoFilter -> **Properties ( double click )**
   Open **Build -> Output -> Output path -> Browse...**

On window, **copy the full path** ( example - C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Exemplos\DataGridViewAutoFilter\CS\DataGridViewAutoFilter\DataGridViewAutoFilter\bin\Debug )

**Open Windows Explore and past** C:\Users\Samir\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Exemplos\DataGridViewAutoFilter\CS\DataGridViewAutoFilter\DataGridViewAutoFilter\bin\Debug ( **is here DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll file** )

**How to install add reference DataGridViewAutoFilter on my project?**

9. **Copy** DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll file **to your project folder**
10. On **your project** click **References -> Add Reference -> Browse** select DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll on folder you paste the file.
11. Now, on DataGridView -> Edit Columns... -> Select Column -> change ColumnType **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn** to **DataGridView*AutoFilter*TextBoxColumn**
12. Build and Start, your project and test the feature.

Answer (score 3):

It's seems to be external assembly you can download from MS and add to your project.
please take a look at the following thread that contains instruction how to do it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winformsdatacontrols/thread/b378e179-3ea6-42de-966e-f0c636891a9e

Comment: The instructions first step is "1. In your Windows Application project, add a reference to the DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll assembly."

Where can I get the DataGridViewAutoFilter.dll ? I can't find it anywhere on MSDN~

Comment: the first link is for download, did you tried to download and compile the project?

Comment: yes, thanks. I have since done that and added it as an answer already. I didn't realize before how to make that dll~

Comment: Thanks to you too, I would have upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough points~